# How to organize project using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have started a project where everything is a mess. They are using mercurial.
Each task is a ticket which generates a branch.

They have 2 main branches development and production and like 5 developers.

They merge changes against development branch for review sometimes they get back to fix issues. But at that moment someone created a branch from it.

Then when you want to merge branches to development or even worse to production all gets complicated some people override others changes.

Any ideas on how to organize this?, So far I have created an "stable" branch from where they should create their branches, but not sure if that is the best solution, since at the end we have to merge it with development for test.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you read [standard branching](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching)?

Comment: New to this mercurial area, thanks for the link, I will check it

Answer (score 0):

A named branch for each ticket might be excessive, but why not, it should word.
If developpers merge a branch to the default branch, they shouldn't override other fixes. 2 cases : The merge is going smooth, no conflicts, so no problem, or there is a conflicts, then the developper has to understand what he is merging, and if needed asks help from the other developper who has made modifications in same file.

I would also add, but it's not a Mercurial problem, but a testing problem. Each bug fix should have a non regression test, or unit test, so you're sure that the fix remain stable in the future. Then after each merge, you run the tests and you can be sure that nothing is broken.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, how would you manage each ticket? not as a branch or only as labeled commits?

Comment: For my part, tickets are tickes, they are associated to a release version, so to a release branch, and we fix the tickets in that branch, and then merge it back to default branch from time to time, or when it's finished.